# Why a variable tht I change with a click event dosn't afffect another function that has to do with that variable?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in js:

```
function feed() {

    if(!batut){
    foods.forEach(food => {
        food.addEventListener('click', function() {
            reset();
            imgs[first + 1].style.display = "block"
            txt.innerHTML = "Boss e satul. Doarme ca un porc."  
            feedTime();

} )
    })
    } 

}

function goesAway(){
    reset();
    imgs[2].style.display = "block";
    txt.innerHTML = "L-ai batut pe Boss si pleaca!"
    clearTimeout(timer);
    batut = true;
}
```

First one displays another img when i click one each of the objects.
The second is a function that triggers when i press a button.
When that happens i don't want that the first function to work anymore so I put there var = true in order to change it and dosn't apply to the if in the first but is not working..can someone help?

Comment: Is your issue that the button is still clickable etc?

Comment: yes, i want the click event in the first function to not work after I press another button and call the second function

Comment: Look up removing an event listener.